# Hashicorp Consul - How to do verified TLS from Pods in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, consul, consul-kv

I'm having some difficulty understanding Consul end-to-end TLS. For reference, I'm using Consul in Kubernetes (via the **hashicorp/consul** Helm chart). Only one datacenter and Kubernetes cluster - no external parties or concerns.

I have configured my override **values.yaml** file like so:

```yaml
global:
  datacenter: sandbox

  gossipEncryption:
    secretName: "consul"
    secretKey: "CONSUL_GOSSIP_ENCRYPTION_KEY"

  tls:
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
    serverAdditionalDNSSANs: ["'consul.service.consul'"]

server:
  replicas: 3
  bootstrapExpect: 3
  storage: 20Gi

dns:
  clusterIP: 172.20.53.53

ui:
  service:
    type: 'LoadBalancer'

syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
```

All other values are as default from the shipped **[values.yaml](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/blob/master/values.yaml)** file.

This works, and Consul client logs suggest that all agents area connecting nicely using TLS, with relevant certs and keys being created by (as I understand) the **[Auto-encryption](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/certificates?utm_source=consul.io&utm_medium=docs#auto-encryption-method)** feature of Consul.

What I don't understand is how to initiate a HTTPS connection from an application on Kubernetes, running in a Pod, to a Consul server. Since the Pod's container does not (presumably) have the Consul root CA cert in its trust store, all HTTPS calls fail, as per **wget** example below:

```
# Connect to Pod:
laptop$> kubectl exec -it my-pod sh

# Attempt valid HTTPS connection:
my-pod$> wget -q -O - https://consul.service.consul:8501
Connecting to consul.service.consul:8501 (10.110.1.131:8501)
ssl_client: consul.service.consul: certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

# Retry, but ignore certificate validity issues:
my-pod$> wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://consul.service.consul:8501/v1/status/leader
"10.110.1.131:8300"
```

How am I supposed to enforce end-to-end (verified) HTTPS connections from my apps on Kubernetes to Consul if the container does not recognize the certificate as valid?
Am I misunderstanding something about certificate propagation?

Many thanks - Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with thanks to Hashicorp on their [Consul discussion forum](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/consul-verified-tls-from-pods-in-kubernetes-cluster).

- Create a Kubernetes secret named **consul** with a key named **CONSUL_GOSSIP_ENCRYPTION_KEY** and an appropriate encryption key value.

  - Generate value using `consul keygen`
- Install the **hashicorp/consul** Helm chart with an **values-override.yaml** , such as below:

```
global:
  datacenter: sandbox

  gossipEncryption:
    secretName: "consul"
    secretKey: "CONSUL_GOSSIP_ENCRYPTION_KEY"

  tls:
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
    serverAdditionalDNSSANs: ["'consul.service.consul'"]

server:
  replicas: 3
  bootstrapExpect: 3
  storage: 20Gi

dns:
  clusterIP: 172.20.53.53

ui:
  service:
    type: 'LoadBalancer'

syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
```

- Create an example Pod spec to represent our application.

  - Ensure it mounts the Consul server CA cert secret.
  - Ensure the Pod’s container has **HOST_IP** exposed as an environment variable.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: test-pod
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: consul-consul-ca-cert
    secret:
      secretName: consul-consul-ca-cert
  hostNetwork: false
  containers:
  - name: consul-test-pod
    image: alpine
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    env:
    - name: HOST_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 24h; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: consul-consul-ca-cert
      mountPath: /consul/tls/ca
```

- Upon creation of the Pod, `kubectl exec` into it, and ensure the **ca-certificates** and **curl** packages are installed (I’m using Alpine Linux in this example).

  - (**curl** is purely for testing purposes)

```
#> apk update
#> apk add ca-certificates curl
```

- Copy the mounted Consul server CA certificate into the **/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/** and execute `update-ca-certificates` to add it to the system root CA store.

```
#> cp /consul/tls/ca/tls.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/consul-server-ca.crt
#> update-ca-certificates  # might give a trivial warning - ignore it
```

- The Consul **server** is now accessible (and trusted) over HTTPS as below:

```
#> curl https://consul.service.consul:8501/v1/status/leader
## No TLS errors ##
```

- We also want to talk to the Consul **client** (instead of the server) over HTTPS, for performance reasons.

  - Since the Consul client has its own CA cert, we need to retrieve that from the server.
  - This requires the **consul-k8s** binary, so we need to get that.

```
#> cd /usr/local/bin
#> wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul-k8s/0.15.0/consul-k8s_0.15.0_linux_amd64.zip  # (or whatever latest version is)
#> unzip consul-k8s_0.15.0_linux_amd64.zip
#> rm consul-k8s_0.15.0_linux_amd64.zip
```

- Get the Consul **client** CA cert and install it via `update-ca-certificates` :

```
#> consul-k8s get-consul-client-ca -server-addr consul.service.consul -server-port 8501 -output-file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/consul-client-ca.crt
#> update-ca-certificates  # might give a trivial warning - ignore it
```

- The Consul **client** is now accessible (and trusted) over HTTPS as below:

```
#> curl https://$HOST_IP:8501/v1/status/leader
## No TLS errors ##
```

- We can also access the Consul KV service from the client without issue:

```
#> curl https://$HOST_IP:8501/v1/kv/foo/bar/baz
## No TLS errors ##
```

Naturally, all of the above should be automated by the implementer. These manual steps are purely for demonstration purposes.